# Remove css from all other elements jquery

Tags: jquery

I got the following code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
    <td>CONTENT<li>CONTENT><a id="click"></a><div class="inhalt"></div></li></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the following js:

```
 (function ($) {
   $('li #click').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('hoehe').siblings().removeClass('hoehe');
     $(this).next('.inhalt').toggle(400);
     return false;
  });
}(jQuery));
```

now i would like to remove all "display:block" after clicking an  of another div elsewhere. 
At the moment the div .inhalt is shown and the class .hoehe is added correctly. if i click on another link the .hoehe is removed correctly, but the .inhalt stays with display:block.

thanks

Comment: I think it would be a good thing if you close your tags

Comment: and set different 'id' for `a id="click"`

Comment: the </div> is the one that should be closed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('.inhalt').css('display','');
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(this).next('.inhalt').css("display","none");return false;
```

Comment: this would remove the .inhalt itself and it would never appear

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).css("display", "none")` if you just want to hide the element (but it will not remove the property)

Comment: i want to remove all siblings. but the siblings selector does not work